# Empty line after \paragraph?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, sections-paragraphs

In order to have a subsubsubsection I have used `\paragraph`. The problem is that I get text immediately after the tittle. How do I get an empty line after `\paragraph`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\paragraph}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
  {0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}
text
\subsection{A test subsection}
text
\subsubsection{A test subsubsection}
text
\paragraph{A test paragraph}
text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without packages, simply copy the definition of `\paragraph` from your class and adjust the fourth and fifth arguments of `\@startsection`; for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {-3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}% original: without the minus
                                    {1.5ex plus .2ex}% original {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A test section}
text
\subsection{A test subsection}
text
\subsubsection{A test subsubsection}
text
\paragraph{A test paragraph}
text

\end{document}
```

To have paragraphs with numbering, add

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

to the preamble; to include them in the ToC, add also

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
```

Comment: it did work but how can I make so that I get a 1.1.1.1?

Comment: @silvrfück Add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` to the preamble; to include them in the ToC, add also `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}`. I added this to my answer.